# Allow API access to anyone with sails policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to use my SailsJS API with another node app and keep getting `403 Forbidden` response type.

My action is `scale/create-weight` which creates a database record using the posted data.

I addded the action to `config/policies.js` to allow access from not-logged-in users:

```js
//config/policies.js

module.exports.policies = {

  '*': 'is-logged-in',

  // Bypass the `is-logged-in` policy for:
  'entrance/*': true,
  'account/logout': true,
  'view-homepage-or-redirect': true,
  'deliver-contact-form-message': true,
  'scale/create-weight': true

};
```

And here is how I'm trying to access the API from a separate node app on the same computer:

```js
const querystring = require('querystring')
const http = require('http')

const postData = querystring.stringify({
  'weight' : '10',
  'units' : 'ounces',
  'userId' : '5b8c16301cee97343513e184'
});

var options = {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 1337,
    path: "/api/v1/scale/create-weight",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
      }
};


const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

There server is responding:

```html
STATUS: 403
HEADERS: {"x-powered-by":"Sails <sailsjs.com>","content-type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","content-length":"9","etag":"W/\"9-PatfYBLj4Um1qTm5zrukoLhNyPU\"",
"set-cookie":["sails.sid=s%3AonM7KWW6ohNoOPNiNjXy9NRFapolNavV.eZHy2P1o4WN1BvDbIWAZEsafG9RzaN1D6O%2FgaEjoLq0; Path=/; HttpOnly"],"date":"Sun, 09 Sep 2018 14:
55:58 GMT","connection":"close"}
BODY: Forbidde
BODY: n
No more data in response.
```

What do I have to do to allow outside apps to use the API?

Comment: Change the order. Put the asterisc at the bottom. Sails uses express, so if its registering those middlewares in order, the asterisc is being applied first.

Comment: That's not an issue with sails, what I have above is the default policy file plus the addition of the line I added for my action.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the `csrf` security policy. Although it's not good to turn off the setting completely, you can manage it on a per-route basis in the `config/routes.js` file.

I updated the route, and it works:

```js
'POST /api/v1/scale/create-weight': {
  action: 'scale/create-weight',
  csrf: false
},
```

I will eventually implement an API Key / API Secret security policy so 3rd parties using the API can authenticate that way.